# Where does .new method save in a scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, save

When I create a scaffold for a User, I've noticed that in the create action in my controller, it lists

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
```

and doesn't actually have

```
@user.save
```

anywhere to be found. However, everything seems to work and the new user does get saved to the database. Why is this? Where is this user being saved and why do they use .new instead of just using .create, which would automatically save as well?

Thanks!

Here is my full controller:

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @portion = Portion.new
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @allusers = User.all
    @rentbill = RentBill.last
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email_address, :admin, :pays_tv, :pays_internet)
    end

end
```

Comment: that's not right. there **should** be a call to save somewhere.  paste your controller here. also make sure that you're looking at the right controller.

Comment: It does have save in `respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save .....`

Comment: but isn't this just saying that if there is a save, then respond in the appropriate way? It isn't actually saying to save

Answer (score 0):

It is the correct behaviour:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
   if @user.save
     format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
     format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
   else
     format.html { render :new }
     format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

it is initializing a new user object and then responding. If user object get saved correctly then show 'user was successfully created' otherwise show error message and render new user form again.

Comment: Thanks! So where is the saving to the database actually happening? To my understanding, this is initializing a new user object, not saving it, then it checks whether the user has been saved or not and finds that it has, and therefore renders the :show. My understanding was what that is why you use the create method (.new + .save) vs the new method (.new only)

Comment: Rails has two ways to create a new record 

1. Model.create(attributes)
2. m = Model.new(attributes) followed by m.save. 

Step 1 initiate a new record and save automatically for you but in second step, you are initiating a new object and saving by your self. Second step is useful when you have to some extra processing on the object before saving into database. 

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thanks! So I understand that there are two ways to create a new record. I am just not seeing where in the scaffold the model is saved. The scaffold uses Model.new but I can't see where m.save happens anywhere. It is definitely saving to the database somewhere, I just don't know where that happens.